# Running through two strings and use an 'and' gate on them in c#

Tags: c#, string

My andgate works when I use just 1 bit strings, but anything else, it doesn't work at all and tells me "Specific argument was out of the range of valid values.  Parameter name: startIndex."

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?  And is there a better way to add to the end of a string?  Thanks!

```
private string parsestrings(string s1, string s2)
{
    int n = s1.Length;
    int m = s2.Length;
    int l;
    string s = "";
    if (n > m)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            l = AndGate(s1[i], s2[i]);
            s.Insert(i, IntToBinary(l));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            l = AndGate(s1[i], s2[i]);
            s.Insert(i, IntToBinary(l));
        }
    }
    return s;
}

private int AndGate(int m, int n)
{
    if (m == 1 && n == 1)
        return 1;
    if (m == 1 && n == 0)
        return 0;
    if (m == 0 && n == 1)
        return 0;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems a little off. If `n > m`, then the loop should probably stop at `m` instead of `n`:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= m; i++)
{
    l = AndGate(s1[i], s2[i]);
    s.Insert(i, IntToBinary(l));
}
```

The second loop seems right, though.

A second thought is that the condition `i <= m` should probably be `i < m`, since `s1[m]` is one character past the string.

Finally, you can either follow spender's advice, or use a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) instead. It's generally better for constructing a string than continually adding to and updating a string.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop termination conditions are wrong.  'i <= n' runs the string index off the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

`s.Insert` creates a new string. It doesn't modify the original string.

Did you mean:

```
s = s.Insert ....
```

, also in your case `n > m`, you're iterating all the way to `n`, even though string `s2` is not `n` chars long, so you're going out of bounds.

On the other hand, the Linq `Zip` extension method allows you to do this in a single line:

```
string.Concat(
    s1
       .Zip(s2, (c1,c2) => new {c1, c2})
       .Select(x => x.c1 == '1' && x.c2 == '1' ? '1' : '0'))
```